# Pandas Pivot table- Column to remain even the value is '0' for all index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pivot-table

I was new to pandas and I was manipulating a CSV file to create the pivot table.

The base file used consists of all orders pending in our system. I have categorized the order based on the age_Cate and pivoted the result.

#### Result expected:

[image: Result expected]

The row index is the different order types and the column is the age group. the value is the count of the order pending.

code used to create the above table.

```py
#OFFLINE ORDER - R - pivoted based on order_cate as row , age group as columns & line_number as values (counted)
df_pivot_qty =df_plain_R.pivot_table(values="line_num",index=["order_Cate"],columns="age_Group",aggfunc = "count",fill_value = 0,dropna = False ,margins=True,margins_name="Total").sort_values(['0-4','5-7','8-10','11-15','16-21','22-31','>31',"Total"])[['0-4','5-7','8-10','11-15','16-21','22-31','>31','Total']]
df_pivot_qty
```

The problem is if there is no order pending in the category '>31' - the table not getting formed.

if I remove the sort values command the table appears but the column index is not in order.

Comment: Set up `age_group` as ordered Categorical before the merge and you will have all categories (`observed=False` as default parameter)

Comment: I have modified it's not working.. Same error repeats . is there any specific code to specify category data

Comment: modified how? please provide a fully reproducible DataFrame and the code you used

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the pivot table column to appear even when the column value is zero or Not available

change the data type of the column to category type